# Class 'Illuminate\Encryption\DecryptException' not found in laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, css, laravel

I've faced this problem on my application developed by using Laravel 4.

> Class 'Illuminate\Encryption\DecryptException' not found.

I don't know how this error is produced in my application on the server.
But in my local, it work fine.

Comment: Did you even google it?  http://laravel.io/forum/10-31-2014-class-illuminateencryptiondecryptexception-not-found

Comment: I just get an idea of composer update from google.

Comment: I did composer update and dump-autoload, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @sokhai composer update didnt worked for me,  uploading vendor dir on server fixed the problem.